# ReactJS Static File

Tags: reactjs

I would like to know how to serve txt files like robots.txt and verify.txt in a ReactJS app?

Eg: `http://localhost:3000/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association.txt`

So far I have tried adding the files to the public folder, but the app does not recognize the URL.

Thanks in advance

[image: ReactJS App]

Comment: Create-react-app doesn't have routing built in, so you'll have to add it following something like https://github.com/DavidWells/react-router-tutorial or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2xkPS4G9rg before you'll be able to serve static files the usual way.

Comment: Thanks @bredikhin It can be done via React Router. Please feel free to post it as an answer. I will post a solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following solution works for serving a static file via React JS React Router.

1. Add the file to the public folder
2. Include a route that points to the static file in the public folder Eg: /robots.txt:

**Solution via React Router**

```
const reload = () => window.location.reload();

<Route path="/my-static-file.ext" onEnter={reload} />
```